# Is there any possibility to convert a varbinary image to its file path in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve the image from the database on edit.

But I want it to appear as its file path (which was uploaded previously).

My idea is to convert varbinary to byte[], byte[] to image using MemoryStream and Image to its file path..

Is it possible and can anyone help me with it

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Do you have save somewhere in your database the original path?

Comment: You could do this if theres the original path somewhere!

Comment: I have so far tried only to retrieve the file from the database. but I dont know to which to assign. This one seems wrong. So thought of an alternative and posted the question. FileUploadControl.FileContent = Convert.ToByte(dsModuleDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0]["InvoiceFile"].ToString());

Comment: I think you need two fields one for the byte[] and one for the filepath , dont think you can get the file path from the byte[]

Comment: Yeah @tsukimi is right! Create a field as Filepath to save it, and binary field to store the file!

Comment: @tsukimi yes you are right.. I am trying to find out a way for it.. Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName) is the one that contains the file path

Comment: @Fals You idea seems really good!

Answer (score -1):

You can get the image from the db like shown below.
As for the path, you need to save it in the db when you save the image.

```
public void GetImage(string strSQL)
{

    using( System.Data.IDbConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("constring"))
    {

        lock (con)
        {

            using (System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {

                lock (cmd)
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = strSQL;

                    if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        con.Open();

                    using (System.Data.IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                    {
                        lock (reader)
                        {
                            int i = reader.GetOrdinal("Field1");

                            byte[] baImage;
                            System.Drawing.Image img;
                            using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                            {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[8040]; // sql page size
                                int read;
                                long offset = 0;
                                while ((read = (int)reader.GetBytes(i, offset, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                {
                                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                                    offset += read; // oops! added this later... kinda important
                                } // Whend

                                baImage = ms.ToArray(); // Here's your image as byte array
                                img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); // Here's your image as image
                            } // End Using ms

                        } // End Lock reader

                    } // End Using reader

                } // End Lock cmd

            } // End Using cmd

        } // End Lock con

    } // End using con

} // End Sub GetImage
```

If you want to display the image on the website, you can do it like this (in a new generic handler's process request):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType("image/jpeg");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(baImage);
```